# How to correctly shorten an if-statement in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Okay, I have an if sentence in which I compare a specific value multiple times. I bet there is a shorter way to do this:

```
if(letter == "%" || letter == "+" || letter == "-" || letter == "!")
```

I tried writing it as:

```
if(letter == "%" || "+" || "-" || "!")
```

But it works incorrectly.

Comment: If you are comparing characters it should be `'%'` and not `"%"`, the latter is a string literal which should be compared with `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
string s("%+-!");
if (s.find(letter) != string::npos) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 While it's correct and it's an idiom quite used, I always thought it was a solution in search of a problem :-)

Comment: This looks quite good and wrapped up inside a function could prevent wrong use/make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

That's as short as it can. You could rewrite it though, with some help from Boost it could be

```
if( boost::is_any_of( "%+-!" )( letter ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a switch statement in-stead of an if. It's not less typing, but it does allow you to write "letter" only once. Some programmers like the visual layout of a switch statement. Note of caution, switch only works on scalar types like char (not std::string).

```
switch (letter)
{
  case '%':
  case '+':
  case '-':
  case '!':
     // if letter is %,+,-,!
     // code goes here for matching letter 
     break;
  default:
     // else do something different
     // code goes here for letter that doesn't match
}
```

See bottom of page at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ for a similar example.

Comment: That is not exactly shorter, and it starts getting into multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, I guess mine is more of a clarity & efficiency kind of rewrite. The other answers above are definitely shorter (less typing than mine). ;-)

Comment: Another problem is that you can use the switch statement on chars only, I forgot to state that I was using std::strings.

Comment: Ah good point, if it's a string you can't use the switch statement. Mine only works with a scalar type like char.

Comment: @Speed: The accepted answer exhibits the same problem with not being able to use strings...

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham The accepted answer with five up votes is written using strings and uses strings perfectly. Otherwise the code I just compiled 5 minutes ago wouldn't work.

Comment: @Speed: One of those upvotes is mine.  I thought you meant in your comment here that this doesn't support a case like `"thisisatest"`.  You're using strings to represent your characters is what you're saying...

Comment: @Meryln Morgan-Graham: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
char op[4] = { '%', '+', '-', '!' };
char * opEnd(op + 4);
if (opEnd != find(op, opEnd, letter))
```

Alternatively:

```
if (string("%+-!").find(letter) != string::npos)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that either side of the `||` operator has no knowledge of each other. They're two completely independent expressions. Consequently `"+"` etc. always evaluate as true (think of what would happen if you just wrote `if ("+")` - it decays to a pointer which is non-`NULL`)

Sometimes I find it is cleaner to express this kind of problem using `std::find` and pair of iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void test(const char letter) {
  static const char c[] = {'%', '+', '-', '!'};
  static const char *begin=c, *end=&c[sizeof(c)/sizeof(*c)];
  if (std::find(begin, end, letter) != end) {
    std::cout << "Matched " << letter << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  test('a');
  test('%');
  test('!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the end result is to type as little as possible and attempt to keep your code quick to comprehend by using something familiar like English.

Your code reads something like,'is my letter equal to this and this and this and this'. It may be a bit long winded but it is quite quick to comprehend.

Unfortunately c++ compilers don't really do 'is my letter equal to these'. Which may be English to most of us but not to poor compilers :)

As a programmer you have the power to hide the compiler literacy shortfalls, keep your code comprehendable and also type less.

```
 if( letterIsOneOfThese( letter, "%+-!") )
 {
    // do something

 }


bool letterIsOneOfThese( const char letter, const char* letterList ) 
{
    int len = strlen( letterList );
    while( len-- )
    {
        if( letterList[len] == letter )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: compared to using `std::string` and `find` or `boost::is_any_of` this looks like reinventing the wheel to me.

Comment: Feel free to wrap your boost/std::string whatever implementation you like.  As a coder you spend 80% of your time fixing stuff and so making that stuff immediately comprehendable is a good thing.