# alternate to multiple checks in IF condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

is there some other way to re-write this code?

```
if(i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 198 || i == 41 )
{
     // do something
}
```

what is the other way to ignore this multiple checks in the if condition... do we have anything like **IN statements**(SQL queries) in C++?.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: May be, put them in an array and use `std::find`?

Comment: Put the numbers in sorted order and use `std::binary_search`?

Comment: Or `std::any_of` with a bound `std::equal` (or lambda).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your `=`s should be `==`s.

Comment: @KerrekSB For this few, it's probably not worth the bother.

Comment: Technically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457741/how-to-correctly-shorten-an-if-statement-in-c. This question does have a better title though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is often the case, writing a new function can be very elegant:

```
template <typename Range, typename T>
bool contains(Range range, T element) {
    return std::find(std::begin(range), std::end(range), element) != std::end(range);
}

template <typename T>
bool contains(std::initializer_list<T> range, T element) {
    return contains<std::vector<int>>(range, element);
}
```

I went for the range-based approach, but you could provide overloads that take begin/end iterators too. Also, feel free to use something other than `std::find` in the implementation.

(Do we really have to overload for `std::initializer_list`? Seems strange that we can't deduce it.)

Now we can write:

```
if (contains({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3))
```

Comment: this is maybe pretties of answers, very readable.. but how fast this is compared with the others? Or rather, how much slower it is?

Comment: @Paladin It's pretty must as fast as its implementation. If `std::find` isn't good enough, change it! :D

Comment: It would probably be better to use `container::find`, as they are specialized for the implementation of the container.

Answer (score 2):

Use a static const unordered set:

```
static const std::unordered_set<int> my = { 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13 } ;

auto find = my.find( 8 ) ;
if( find != my.end() )
{
    cout << "found:" << *find << endl ;
}
```

The search complexity is on average O(1).

And should be thread safe.

Comment: I have found that, especially for small(er) sets, `std::set` tends to be quicker than `std::unordered_set`. While the time complexity of `std::unordered_set::find` is better, the constant cost appears to be bigger than the cost of the binary search in `std::set::find`.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Since this container is constructed only once, lower cost of find is more important.

Comment: @2015 What I mean is that the cost of the one lookup for `std::unordered_set::find` is more expensive than the few lookups for `std::set::find`. See [example for `set`](http://ideone.com/lqjdRf) and [example for `unordered_set`](http://ideone.com/8aOG97). Time complexity is not everything, the cost of each individual operation also has to be taken into account.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Yes, set was faster for small values, but at some point >~250 elements( and before if inserted in sorted order ), unordered became faster. Measuring the used case is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

A simple switch-case is the most readible:

```
   switch (i) {
      case 0:
      case 4:
      case 6:
      case 8:
      case 9:
      case 19:
      case 198:
      case 41:
        // DO THINGS
        break;
      default:
        // OTHERS
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static const int options[] = {0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 19, 198, 41};
if (std::find(std::begin(options), std::end(options), i) != options.end()) {
    // do something
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, as long as you keep options sorted, you can use this

```
static const int options[] = {0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 19, 198, 41};
if (std::binary_search(std::begin(options), std::end(options), i)) {
    // do something
}
```

which should be faster.

For small array I think it doesn't really matter which variant you pick.

Comment: It's certainly improved by being more data-driven.

Comment: I guess. But IMHO ifs may be faster while number of options is small

Comment: If you ensure that options is sorted, you may use `std::binary_search` instead of `std::find`

Answer (score 1):

Well, in C (and also, of course, C++), you could:

```
switch(i)
{
   case 0:
   case 4:
   case 6:
   case 8:
   case 9:
   case 19:
   case 198:
   case 41:  // do something
             break;
}
```

Of course, the compiler will generate pretty much the same code as your original bunch of ifs, but maybe this looks clearer?

Comment: "Of course, the compiler...": Not necessarily true! The compiler can optimise such a switch statement to perform a binary search, for instance. Or build a jump table (but not in this case). The `switch`-statement should be _at least_ as fast as the `if`-statement.

Comment: I like this. Almost as intuitive as if.

Comment: I don't really like this approach. If I see a `switch`, I'm expecting there to be multiple different cases. I'd figure it out quickly, but it's still a bit jarring.

Comment: @TonyK: The compiler can apply the same optimizations to the `if`  statement.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: That's why it is useful to have `default: break; // do nothing`

Comment: @MSalters: "The compiler can apply the same optimizations...": In principle, yes. But I would be surprised to see any real-world compiler do that.

Comment: @TonyK: It wouldn't be that surprising, to be honest. If the jump table building is done by a peephole optimizer, and the unoptimized translation of the switch-statement is identical to the unoptimized translation of the if-statement, the peephole optimizer will build jump tables for both cases.

Comment: @MSalters: I would be _very_ surprised if a production-quality compiler left `switch`-statement optimisation to the peephole optimiser.

Comment: @TonyK:  Details. You get the same optimizations if the optimizer runs on any translated representation of the input in which the particular form of this `if` statement coincides with a `switch` statement. And as both compare a single value against a set of constants, that's not terribly unlikely.

Comment: @MSalters: Perhaps we mean different things by 'peephole'. Anyway, GCC optimises the two alternatives completely differently (although there is not much to choose between the speed of the results).

Answer (score 1):

Writing such statement is an error

```
if(i = 0 || i = 4 || i = 6 || i = 8 || i = 9 || i = 19 || i = 198 || i = 41 )
```

You require == operator for comparison.
Now since you are comparing one type of value against multiple. using switch statement is better solution. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Use an initializer list (or vector) with std::any_of:

```
static const auto accepted = { 0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 19, 198, 41 };
if( std::any_of(std::begin(accepted), std::end(accepted),
    [&i](int x) { return i == x; }) {

    // do something
}
```

(this was proposed by @JosephMansfield in a comment)

Edit: This can be optimized by reordering the integer values, optimizing for the most hit value first.

Comment: Yes. any_of is semantically equivalent to calling std::find_if and comparing the result to the end of the sequence (so it performs a linear search to the first match).

Answer (score 0):

You can use STL MAP ... Try this..

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

map<int,int>mp;
int main()
{
    int i;

    mp[0]=mp[4]=mp[6]=mp[8]=mp[9]=mp[19]=mp[198]=mp[41]=1;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(mp[i])
    {
        //do something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disastrous! `mp[i]` _creates_ the entry if it doesn't exist. You need `if (mp.find(i) != mp.end())`.

Comment: mp[i] would actually work, since default value for integer I believe is 0... but nevertheless, this isn't the right way to go.. too slow. plus is allocated on the heap

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yap "To steal from, or rob someone. especially jewerly and other valuble items." :D :D what you wanted to say was "yep"... sorry for being grammar nazi, but this was just too funny

Answer (score 0):

With a short, fixed list like this, you can look for an integer `n` such that all the elements have a different remainder when divided by `n`. For instance, `n = 14` does the trick here, because the remainders `mod 14` are 0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 2, and 13. So you can do this:

```
static const int remainder_table[14] = {
    0, 0, 198, 0, 4, 19, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 41
} ;
if (remainder_table[i % 14] == i) {
    // do something
}
```

**Warning**: This is not necessarily faster that the original `if`-statement! That depends on the speed of hardware division, and the compiler's optimising capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare `i` with constant - which is known at complie time, you can use TMP.

```
namespace detail
{
    template <int ...Args>
    struct CompFunc;

    template <int num, int ...Args>
    struct CompFunc<num, Args...>
    {
        static constexpr bool f(int i)
        {
            return (i == num) || CompFunc<Args...>::f(i);
        }
    };
    template <>
    struct CompFunc<>
    {
        static constexpr bool f(int i)
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
}

template <int ...Args>
constexpr bool any_of_const(int i)
{
    return detail::CompFunc<Args...>::f(i);
}
```

and

```
if (any_of_const<0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 19, 198, 41>(i))
{
    ...
}
```

[(live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14388d835ef97331)